# How to save Dataset<Row> in mySQL in spark?

Tags: azure, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, azure-data-lake

I am using spark standalone cluster in my scenario. I want to read read a JSON file from Azure data lake and using SparkSQL and do some query over it and save the result into a mysql database. I don't know how to do it. A small help will be a great.

```
package com.biz.Read_from_ADL;

import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("Java Spark SQL basic example").getOrCreate();

        Dataset<Row> df = spark.read().json("adl://pare.azuredatalakestore.net/EXCHANGE_DATA/BITFINEX/ETHBTC/MIDPOINT/BITFINEX_ETHBTC_MIDPOINT_2017-06-25.json");

        //df.show();
        df.createOrReplaceTempView("trade");

        Dataset<Row> sqlDF = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM trade");
        sqlDF.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: probably this article should help :- https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/data-sources/sql-databases.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to first define the connection properties and jdbc url.

```
import java.util.Properties

val connectionProperties = new Properties()
connectionProperties.put("user", "USER_NAME")
connectionProperties.put("password", "PASSWORD")
val jdbc_url = ... // <- use mysql url   
import org.apache.spark.sql.SaveMode

spark.sql("select * from diamonds limit 10").withColumnRenamed("table", "table_number")
  .write
  .mode(SaveMode.Append) // <--- Append to the existing table
  .jdbc(jdbc_url, "diamonds_mysql", connectionProperties)
```

Refer [here](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/data-sources/sql-databases.html) for more detail.